# Is GCC a LALR(1) compiler?

Tags: gcc

Can anyone deny/confirm this??

Answer (score 1):

It can't be, at least not entirely -- the C grammar doesn't fit LALR(1).

Comment: Ignoring "prove" for the moment, there are a couple of problem areas I can recall. One deals with if/then/else, and matching each else with the right if. Another is basically the same as the C++ "most vexing parse" -- it doesn't arise as often in C, but can anyway, and an LALR(1) parser basically *can't* really parse it.

Answer (score 1):

http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-08/msg00099.html

> The Gcc parser is a LALR grammar file for Bison, which is a LALR parser
>   generator.
>   Therefore, if you want to say that, gcc is LALR.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GCC is LALR.

"The Gcc parser is a LALR grammar file for Bison, which is a LALR parser
generator.
Therefore, if you want to say that, gcc is LALR."

Answer (score 0):

[This discussion](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2004-08/msg00077.html) (though old) says gcc is LALR while for C++ it is a hand-written recursive descent one.

Answer (score 0):

The quote above is out of date. All parser of GCC is hand written now.  And I am pretty sure cpp is a lalr(k) parser.